# Why did not I get the Selfie hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash

Why don't I have the Selfie hat yet? I already answered one of my own questions.

Is there a bug or something glitched?  Can someone report this to moderators?

I hope this gets fixed because I really want my Selfie hat before christmas.

Can someone point out if I didn't do something right if I didn't do something correctly.

Comment: I have a solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question was asked before Winterbash began, and therefore is not eligible for the Selfie hat.

Both the question and the answer should be posted during the Winterbash to qualify you for Selfie.

Comment: too bad for me. =( But thanks anyway.

Answer (score -3):

Click on your profile at the top of the screen (a little to the right of the middle). This takes you to your profile page. Click on "more info" next to your name. Then click on the link next to the hats. See photo.[image]

Comment: They never told me that.

Comment: Hang on, I now realize what you meant. Give me a minute to post better instructions.